# Python Eve - Dynamic Lookup Filters using authenticated user informations

Tags: mongodb, eve

I'm a newby using MongoDB and Eve; I have a problem setting up a dynamic lookup filters.
My use case is to include in a pre_GET only documents whose _id is included in a list (array) present in the profile of the (authenticated) user.
Now, when this list is static, it's working fine like this:

```
class BCryptAuth(BasicAuth):
def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
    # use Eve's own db driver; no additional connections/resources are used
    accounts = app.data.driver.db['people']
    account = accounts.find_one({'lastname': username})
    return account and \
    bcrypt.hashpw(password, account['password']) == account['password']

# Hook Test
def pre_GET(resource, request, lookup):
    lookup["_id"] = {'$in': ['5a19808f65a98412dba4b683', '5a1b06d365a98412a4445fa0'] }

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app = Eve(auth=BCryptAuth)   
    # Hook Test
    app.on_pre_GET += pre_GET
    # End Hook Test
```

My need is to substitute the line

```
lookup["_id"] = {'$in': ['5a19808f65a98412dba4b683', '5a1b06d365a98412a4445fa0'] }
```

with the content of the array "canAccess" present in the authenticated user profile (a document in the collection people) - something like (pseudocode)
SELECT the content of array canAccess where lastname = authenticated_user().
This is the document representing the user:

```
{
        "_updated": "Sat, 25 Nov 2017 14:39:11 GMT",
        "firstname": "barack",
        "lastname": "obama",
        "role": [
            "copy",
            "author"
        ],
        "canAccess": [
            "5a1b06d365a98412a4445fa0",
            "5a1c5c9265a984120caf7e0b"
        ],
        "_created": "Sat, 25 Nov 2017 14:39:11 GMT",
        "_id": "5a19808f65a98412dba4b683",
        "_etag": "758056ac49d156526858bd3a8b4922d65231942f"
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Giulio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flask `g` to store the `user_id` in the per-request application context, so you can retrieve it inside the hook.

In `check_auth`:

```
from flask import g

def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
    people = app.data.driver.db['people']
    user = people.find_one({'lastname': username})
    g.user_id = user['_id']
    return account and \
    bcrypt.hashpw(password, account['password']) == account['password']
```

Then you can access your data from the array inside the hook by doing the same done in the `check_auth` to retrieve the account, roughly like this:

```
from flask import g

def pre_GET(resource, request, lookup):
    user_id = getattr(g, 'user_id', None)
    people = app.data.driver.db['people']
    user = accounts.find_one({'_id': user_id})
    lookup["_id"] = {'$in': user['canAcess']}
```

Comment: Many thanks gcw, it seems to work well. BTW, do you see some performance problem should this solution be used in a huge env (millions of documents)?

Comment: Not sure @giulio_l, I haven't used in an environment like this.